# Siyum on Tanach

Tags: tanach, siyum

A friend of mine recently did a siyum on Nevi'im. However, his Trei Asar did not have a text in the back for a siyum (a "Hadran"; see an example at the bottom [here](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=37&daf=73&format=pdf)). Does anyone know of a text for a Siyum on different parts of Tanach? Are there variations from the standard version? Points to consider:

- Do you say Hadran Alach Nevi'im? Hadran Alach Sifrei Nevi'im?
- Do you mention all the sons of Rav Pappa?
- At the end there is usually a phrase that says BeZchut Kol HaTannaim HaKetuvim Bo. How is this adapted to Tanach?

[Note: This question is about the text of the siyum ceremony, not about what portions of Tanach qualify for a siyum.]

Comment: http://www.sefaria.org/Hadran_for_Tanach

Answer (score 7):

In the [Artscroll Iyov](http://www.artscroll.com/Books/soih.html) - from Rabbi Shimon Schwab Zatzal it mentions that there is there is no need for a Hadran on Torah Sh'Biksav. The whole intention of saying Hadran is to highlight the perpetual need for Chazorah of the Torah Sh'Baal Peh, which was not intended to
be written, it was supposed to be memorized.

Comment: Apparently REB MOSHE FEINSTEIN ZATZAL SAID YOU COULD

Comment: from  Rabbi Bechoffer shiur

Comment: @simchashatorah even if you can make a siyum on it with a seudat mitzva doesn't mean there is a 'hadran' text.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a video of Rabbi Reisman's text that he said when he made a Siyum on Sefer Yirmyahu.

> Do you say Hadran Alach Nevi'im? Hadran Alach Sifrei Nevi'im?

I remember him saying it but it is not in the video.

> Do you mention all the sons of Rav Pappa? At the end there is usually a phrase that says BeZchut Kol HaTannaim HaKetuvim Bo. How is this adapted to Tanach?

Seems not. He said Bzchus Nevim Vitzadikim.

Here it is: http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=1noPWeX6guM#t=469s

---

Rabbi Bechoffer, it seems, wrote his own Hadran based on the Hadran, in the Siddur OTZAR HATEFILLAH, for Chumash. Listen to his Hadran in this Shiur  (Fair warning, the Siyum was on Purim):
http://teachittome.org/YGB/Shoftim_23a.mp3