# Protocol for unconventional Siyum

Tags: halacha, kaddish, siyum

What is the protocol for [an unconventional Siyum](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/17970/5) (see the linked-to page)?

Do you say Hadran?  If so, what would you say in the Hadran if, for example, you learned [a Daf of Gemara](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/17971/5) over the course of a year?  Do you say Kaddish?  Do you say the Papas, etc.?

Comment: I think you say the Mamas *and* the Papas. And you dedicate it to the one you love.

Comment: I heard there's a hadran for nevi'im found in the Sidur Otzar HaTefilos (I don't have that sidur, though, so I can't check). I don't know what you'd say instead of וזכות כל התנאים והאמוראים יעמוד בעדני, but I heard that the hadran for nevi'im is כל הנביאים

Comment: @BA that's not really what troubles me. What if you learned 2 Perakim of Gemara? What if you learn Hilchoth Ta'aruvoth in the Tur?

Comment: related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/13349/759 (ping @ba)