# Can one make a Siyum During Shiva?

Tags: halacha-theory, torah-study, siyum, sitting-shiva

Related to [this](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/57373/can-you-make-a-siyum-on-something-in-torah-without-understanding-it), [this](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/31817/what-level-of-understanding-is-required-in-learning-for-purposes-of-making-a-s?noredirect=1&lq=1), [this](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/51294/can-a-mourner-avel-learn-torah-on-shabbat) and [this](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/13349/siyum-on-tanach).

During Shiva, a mourner is allowed to study Sefer [Iyov](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/281610/jewish/Study-of-Torah-During-Shiva.htm).  Assuming that learning this one sefer is enough to make a siyum, could a mourner make a siyum during the shiva to mark his completion of what he was allowed to do?

Here is one implication -- if, for example, the shiva overlapped the 9 days, could the mourner (and, OR, anyone making a shiva call) then eat meat?

Once one is allowed to study Torah (all the moreso, a daf of gemara that deals with mourning and which, according to the linked answer, be enough to justify a siyum for a non-learned person) can one mark the completion of that study. Does the mourner have to wait until the end of shloshim and make his siyum well after finishing learning?

Comment: Even if he could make it, could he attend it?

Comment: Can he read the last bit of Iyov?

Comment: @Heshy Indeed https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/84470/may-one-learn-torah-from-an-unacceptable-source-on-tisha-bav-in-the-context-of/84881#comment265351_84470 But the question stands if he had previously learned all of Iyov before out of order except some random sad chapter and now finishes it

Comment: @Heshy this is the quote from the Chabad website "Thus, while the bereaved may not study the Bible and the Prophets, the Talmud and the Midrash, he may read the book of Job, the story of the classic mourner. He may also read the poetry of anguish, the book of Lamentations (that is read on the ninth of Av, when we commemorate the Temple's destruction), and also parts of Jeremiah that foretell doom." While it mentions "parts' for Yirmiyahu, it doesn't for Iyov or Eicha.